# How to search some text in a PDF File

Tags: linux, pdf, search

I would like to search some text in a PDF file. For example, where is the word "go to" in my PDF? If you find it, what page is there?

I find this command line :

```
find /TEMP -name 'manu.pdf' -exec pdftotext {} - \; | grep "go to"
```

It result some elements.

I would like to get the page number of my result. How to retrieve that item?

Answer (score 7):

[pdfgrep](http://pdfgrep.sourceforge.net/) seems to do this. From the [man page](http://pdfgrep.sourceforge.net/manpage.html):

```
-n, --page-number
Prefix each match with the number of the page where it was found.
```

Comment: Thank you very much, sorry for this topic, I should have to see this page!

Comment: Sorry but pdfgrep isn't installed on my server. I install poppler-utils but I  can't install pdfgrep. So, I haven't any result

Comment: Why can't you install pdfgrep ?

Comment: On Centos 5.7 and ubuntu 9.10 : apt-get (or yum) install pdfgrep : No package pdfgrep available. I download the 1.3.0.tar.gz, unzip, ./configure : configure: error: Package requirements (poppler-cpp) were not met: No package 'poppler-cpp' found. I can do nothing

Comment: Pdfgrep is available from Ubuntu 10.10 on. I've just successfully installed it in a Ubuntu 11 VM

Answer (score 1):

As per default, pdftotext does insert form feed characters (0xC) between pages. You can count them up to the appearance of the word you search for.

Another way is to use the `bbox` option:

```
 Generate an XHTML file containing bounding box information for each word in the file.
```

Here, every word is enclosed in a `page` container. So you can take the index+1 of the `page` your word is in as page number

Comment: Do you have an example to get it?

Answer (score 1):

Recoll can search PDF documents. It has a command line mode, but the GUI will be more helpful in detailing where the matches occur, and it will let you click open the document at the right position.